# Migrating old Delphi 7 code to Delphi XE - QForms.dcu not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I just bought and installed Delphi XE and was hoping to compile my old D7 project there.

However, I hava a source file that "uses QForms" and that generates a "file not found: qforms.dcu" and I can find no relevant reference to what to do about that file googling around...

Any idea how to solve it?

Rgds
PM

Comment: You Delphi 7 project must be a cross-plataform which uses CLX instead of VCL, So you must migrate you project to VCL in order to compile in Delphi XE.

Comment: Does your project also use "Forms" (no "Q")? In that case "uses QForms" is likely a leftover from some experiment, and you can try deleting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QForms` is from [CLX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Library_for_Cross_Platform), the Qt based cross-platform library that was introduced with Delphi 6/Kylix. So far as I know, CLX is no longer shipped with Delphi.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Stick with Delphi 7.
2. Port the code to VCL. This will tie you to the Windows platform.
3. Get Delphi XE2 and use FireMonkey since clearly at some point in time this code was intended to be cross-platform.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! 1. Trying not to...;-) 2. Any tips on how or where to find info for this? 3. Cross-plattform not needed.

Comment: @PetterMagnusson: Basically, you can just search your uses clause for units starting with 'Q', and remove the 'Q'. They were consistent in using that method (`QForms` vs. `Forms`).

Comment: Just add unit alias `QForms=Forms`. If portability is not needed, it raises the question why Qt is there.